# Alfresco Community edition-5.1.x in workflow Move Document on Workflow Approve or Reject

Tags: java, alfresco, alfresco-share

I am new to alfresco community edition-5.1.x i have created workflow activiti using kickstart via eclipse, I deployed into alfresco share its working fine,In that user used custom workflow activiti form user assign to another user for the approval once approve the activiti the document move to approved folder within a document Library of a site if reject the activiti the document to rejected folder within a document Library of a site , Is this possible please help out.

Comment: Your question is unclear and not complete. Read the how to ask a question and re-write it.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use a workflow starttasklistener , and use it to move the file

Add listener to you bpmn20:

```
<userTask id="mytask" name="mytask" activiti:assignee="${mymodel.myassoc.properties.userName}" >

<activiti:taskListener event="create"  class="com.mycomp.StartTasklistener"/>
</userTask
```

Code in com.mycomp.StartTasklistener will look like this:

```
public class StartTasklistener extends TaskCreateListener 
public void notify(DelegateTask task) throws Exception {
   if (execution.getVariable("mymodel_myfiletomove") == null ){
      ActivitiScriptNode fileScriptNode= (ActivitiScriptNode) execution.getVariable("mymodel_myfiletomove");
      NodeRer newparent = ....
      serviceRegistry.getFileFolderService().move(newparent , fileScriptNode.getNodeRef())
   }
 }
```